# how to fix cannot find module graceful-fs error?

Tags: angularjs, windows, gruntjs

I have grunt configured and when I run 'grunt serve' I get this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'graceful-fs'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
```

how can I fix this error and run my app?

Comment: can we assume you have that module? Nothing was mentioned about it or any other steps you have taken to troubleshoot

Comment: sounds like you didn't even read the error message.

Answer (score 2):

Try

1 - npm cache clear

2 - remove node_modules

3 - npm install

Answer (score 0):

The solution for on windows 10 was

- Removing the current npm directory in the main directory nodejs/node_modules
- Cloning the last build of npm https://github.com/npm/npm.git into  the nodejs/node_modules dir